# Changing the starting row of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA code which works on the data starting from Row2 of worksheet. Instead of Row2, I want it to start from row5. I tried to change it a little but I was not successful. How can i do this? please. thanks.

```
Sub Intervals()    
    Dim R As Range, C As Range

    With Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
            For Each R In .Cells
                Set C = .Find(R.Value, R, , 1, , , 2)
                If (C.Address <> R.Address) * (C.Row > R.Row) Then
                    R.Offset(, 7) = C.Row - R.Row - 1
                Else
                    R.Offset(, 7) = "na"
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Offset(4).Resize(.Rows.Count - 4)` something like this

Comment: hmm. this didn't work  :(

Comment: You can put an `If R.Row > 4 Then` before `Set C = .Find(R.Value, R, , 1, , , 2)`, this doesn't change the selected `Range` but it'll stop actions from occurring.

Comment: When I add If R.Row > 4, this time it gives compile error "Next without for".

Answer (score 0):

I found another way:

```
Sub Intervals
Dim R as range, c As Range
With Range("A5").CurrentRegion
       'MsgBox .Cells.Address 'Just to show you the Address of Currentregion.!!
            For Each R In .Cells
                Set c = .Find(R.Value, R, , 1, , , 2)
                If (c.Address <> R.Address) * (c.Row > R.Row) Then
                    R.Offset(, 7) = c.Row - R.Row - 1
                Else
                    R.Offset(, 7) = "na"
                End If
            Next
       End With
End Sub
```